# Formula for partial sum of (10)/(10n+1)

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm trying to find $S_n$ of an infinite series, and I'm having trouble. Here is the equation:

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{10}{10n+1}$$

This gives me these terms:

$$S_n = \frac{10}{11}+\frac{10}{21}+\frac{10}{31}+\frac{10}{41}+ ... + \frac{10}{10n+1}$$

After I calculate the terms of $S_n$, I get:

$$S_n = \frac{10}{11},\frac{20}{32},\frac{30}{63},\frac{40}{104}, ... $$

Obviously the top is 10n, but I'm having trouble with the bottom. I recognize a pattern in the differences of the terms, mainly that each is separated by the previous difference + 10:

$$S_2-S_1=21$$

$$S_3-S_2=31$$

$$S_4-S_3=41$$

But I have no idea how to translate that into a formula. Note that I am aware that the series diverges, but I would still like to create a formula with which I can take the limit of infinity to verify that it diverges. Any suggestions?

EDIT: Apparently I'm asking the wrong question. What I'm essentially trying to figure out is how to determine whether the series converges or diverges based on the information available. I can use intuition to come to the conclusion it's divergent, but how do I do it mathematically?

Comment: the series is infinite.

Comment: $$\sum \frac{10}{10n+1}\geq \sum \frac{1}{2n}$$ then the series **DOSEN'T converge**.

Comment: I should have specified, and I'll edit the question: I'm aware that the series is divergent, but I would like to create a formula and take the limit to infinity to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

The $S=\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{10}{10k+1}$ series is divergent. The parial sums have closed-form. Let denote

$$S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{10}{10k+1}.$$

Then in terms of [digamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DigammaFunction.html)

$$S_n = \psi\left(n+\frac{11}{10}\right) - \psi\left(\frac{1}{10}\right) - 10.$$

Here [$\psi\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)$](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=PolyGamma%5B1%2F10%5D) has an elementary closed-form, but I don't know about an alternate form of the other $\psi$ term. The first few elements in the sequence are

$$0, \frac{10}{11},\frac{320}{231},\frac{12230}{7161},\frac{573040}{293601},\frac{3573450}{1663739},\frac{234617840}{101488079},\frac{17672747430}{7205653609},\dots$$

In general if the following sum exists, then:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{a}{bk+c} = \frac ab \left( \psi\left(\frac cb + n+1\right) - \psi\left(\frac cb + 1\right) \right).$$

---

To answer the modified question we could use [direct comparison test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_comparison_test). As @idm mentioned, since

$$\frac{10}{10n+1}\geq\frac{1}{2n} \geq 0,$$

and because $\sum \frac{1}{2n}$ diverges it follows that $\sum \frac{10}{10n+1}$ also diverges.

Comment: Yikes. That is way more advanced than I bargained for - I absolutely have no idea what is going on there. I think I'm asking the wrong question. I suppose the question I should be asking is, how do I use mathematical means (rather than intuition) to tell if that series diverges without creating a formula with which to run a limit test?

Comment: @Todd All right, I've answered your other question too.

Comment: Thank you for your responses. That is an example of the Squeeze Theorem, correct? Also, how do we know $\sum{\frac{1}{2n}}$ diverges - is that just common knowledge that I missed, or is there a specific reason you used $\sum{\frac{1}{2n}}$ in this instance?

Comment: @Todd Is not the squeeze theorem, it's just a comparison test. And yes, its common knowledge that $\sum\frac{1}{n}$ diverges. It's the first example of a divergent series taught in every Calculus course, book , etc.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I can think of is a comparison test.

$\frac {10}{10n + 1} > \frac {9}{10n}$

If $\sum \frac {9}{10n}$ diverges (which it does) then your series diverges by the comparison test.

Comment: Both diverge...

Comment: @BobDobbs thanks...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that there is an elementary formula for the partial sums of the series. But you can represent it in terms of some special functions like digamma function or harmonic number.

Another way to show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{10}{10n+1}$ diverges is [the integral test](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral_test_for_convergence). According to this test OP's series has the "same character" of the improper integral $\int_1^\infty \frac{10}{10x+1}dx$ which evaluates to $$\lim\limits_{M\to\infty}\ln(10x+1)\left.\right\rvert_1^M=\lim\limits_{M\to\infty}M-\ln11\longrightarrow\infty.$$ Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{10}{10n+1}$ is a divergent series.